# Columns in sql query are not grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a problem with the following sql select query. The columns are not aggregated by the group by command.

```
SELECT  
    Dept.Name AS DeptName, COUNT (T.Id) AS TotalServiceNumber,
    (Case when SS.Status <> 'Resolved' then COUNT (T.Id) end) AS UnresolvedNumber,
    (Case when T.FixTime < '120' then COUNT(T.FixTime) end) AS ResolvedLessThanTwoHoursNumber,
    (Case when T.FixTime > '120' then COUNT(T.FixTime) end) AS ResolvedMoreThanTwoHoursNumber,

FROM
    dbo.Tickets AS T,
    dbo.ServiceStatuses AS SS,
    dbo.ComputerDesks AS Desk,
    dbo.Personnels AS Person,
    dbo.Departments AS Dept
WHERE
    SS.Id = T.ServiceStatusId
    AND T.ComputerDeskId = Desk.Id
    AND Desk.PersonnelId = Person.Id
    AND Person.DepartmentId = Dept.Id

GROUP BY
    Dept.Name, SS.Status, T.FixTime
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
DeptName |  TotalServiceNr  | UnresolvedNumber  |   LessThanTwo |   MoreThanTwo 
DeptA    |  8               | NULL              |   8           |   NULL        
DeptB    |  1               | 1                 |   NULL        |   1           
DeptC    |  4               | NULL              |   NULL        |   4           
DeptA    |  38              | NULL              |   NULL        |   38          
DeptB    |  55              | NULL              |   55          |   NULL        
DeptC    |  7               | NULL              |   7           |   NULL        
...
```

Expected result:

```
DeptName |  TotalServiceNr  | UnresolvedNumber  |   LessThanTwo |   MoreThanTwo 
DeptA    |  46              | NULL              |   8           |   38      
DeptB    |  56              | 1                 |   55          |   NULL            
DeptC    |  11              | NULL              |   7           |   4
```

What I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: Are you after all ServiceStatus rows grouped into one result regardless of whether they're resolved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT  
    Dept.Name AS DeptName, COUNT (T.Id) AS TotalServiceNumber,
    sum(Case when SS.Status <> 'Resolved' then 1 else 0 end) AS UnresolvedNumber,
    sum(Case when T.FixTime <= '120' then 1 else 0 end) AS ResolvedLessThanTwoHoursNumber,
    sum(Case when T.FixTime > '120' then 1 else 0 end) AS ResolvedMoreThanTwoHoursNumber,

FROM
    dbo.Tickets AS T,
    dbo.ServiceStatuses AS SS,
    dbo.ComputerDesks AS Desk,
    dbo.Personnels AS Person,
    dbo.Departments AS Dept
WHERE
    SS.Id = T.ServiceStatusId
    AND T.ComputerDeskId = Desk.Id
    AND Desk.PersonnelId = Person.Id
    AND Person.DepartmentId = Dept.Id

GROUP BY
    Dept.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TotalServiceNumber, SUM(UnresolvedNumber), SUM(ResolvedLessThanTwoHoursNumber), SUM(ResolvedMoreThanTwoHoursNumber)
FROM (
    SELECT  
        Dept.Name AS DeptName, COUNT (T.Id) AS TotalServiceNumber,
        (Case when SS.Status <> 'Resolved' then COUNT (C.Id) end) AS UnresolvedNumber,
        (Case when T.FixTime < '120' then COUNT(T.FixTime) end) AS ResolvedLessThanTwoHoursNumber,
        (Case when T.FixTime > '120' then COUNT(T.FixTime) end) AS ResolvedMoreThanTwoHoursNumber,

    FROM
        dbo.Tickets AS T,
        dbo.ServiceStatuses AS SS,
        dbo.ComputerDesks AS Desk,
        dbo.Personnels AS Person,
        dbo.Departments AS Dept
    WHERE
        SS.Id = T.ServiceStatusId
        AND T.ComputerDeskId = Desk.Id
        AND Desk.PersonnelId = Person.Id
        AND Person.DepartmentId = Dept.Id
    GROUP BY Dept.Name, SS.Status, T.FixTime
) GROUPED
GROUP BY
    TotalServiceNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
      Dept.Name AS DeptName
    , COUNT (T.Id) AS TotalServiceNumber
    ,COUNT(Case when SS.Status <> 'Resolved' then 1 ELSE NULL end) AS UnresolvedNumber
    ,COUNT(Case when T.FixTime < '120' then 1 ELSE NULL end) AS ResolvedLessThanTwoHoursNumber
    ,COUNT(Case when T.FixTime > '120' then 1 ELSE NULL end) AS ResolvedMoreThanTwoHoursNumber

FROM
    dbo.Tickets AS T INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceStatuses AS SS
ON SS.Id = T.ServiceStatusId
INNER JOIN dbo.ComputerDesks AS Desk
ON T.ComputerDeskId = Desk.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Personnels AS Person
ON Desk.PersonnelId = Person.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Departments AS Dept
Person.DepartmentId = Dept.Id
GROUP BY Dept.Name
```

Also use `ON` syntax for your joins.

Comment: It should give you error that Status and FixTime is not in group by (I haven't actually check the query)